# Downloading and saving file by using wget in shell_exec

Tags: php, wget, shell-exec

I want to download files from commandline
when I run the command in shell it will work but when I want to execute it in PHP,No result

```
$cmd='wget http://cvs.snort.org/viewcvs.cgi/snort/rules/dns.rules'
$output=shell_exec($cmd);
echo "<pre>$output</pre>";
```

I just wanted to download from this site

any help would be appreciated

how can i correct this?

if the solution is Curl how can I write it

Comment: You can correct highlighting of code!

Answer (score 2):

Use [cURL](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php). Like [this](http://jonasjohn.de/snippets/php/curl-example.htm).

Comment: there isn't any solution with wget?

Comment: There is. But shelling out is bad practice (and a bad habit to get into, think of future security implications) if you don't absolutely need to.

Comment: In curl there are many functions `ch = curl_init();`
            `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, TRUE);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, TRUE);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
            $head = curl_exec($ch);`

Comment: Did you google? This tutorial looks like it's as simple as it gets http://www.jonasjohn.de/snippets/php/curl-example.htm

Comment: I used it,it shows the content but I searched the files that I downloaded,it hasn't been downloaded

Comment: always when I download files they will go to /root but here when I search them the file doesn't exists well! is it possible that it will be download in another location!!!????? I'm confused

Comment: Do you mean save to disk? You did not say that.

Comment: well yes download and save in a folder

Answer (score 1):

> file_get_contents(
>   'http://cvs.snort.org/viewcvs.cgi/snort/rules/dns.rules' );

does the same thing

Comment: Yes! I got it it will show me the output but I want to download the file too.

Comment: echo file_put_contents('http://cvs.snort.org/viewcvs.cgi/snort/rules/dns.rules', $file_path );

Comment: marabutt it just shows the content I want to download it too,by the way thank you very much

Comment: What do you mean 'download'? You can't show the content without downloading it...

Comment: why not?it is a link that will go from that site

Answer (score 0):

By default wget write document to file

For prevent default use option:

`wget -q -O /dev/stdin google.com`

Comment: And yes, better if you use cURL.

Comment: I must use it where?in shell or in exec_shell?

Comment: Use cURL. If you don` have cURL that use file_get_contents. But if your want `wget`. You must use that command in `exec_shell`